# How do I use fwrite() to write a struct to a file?

Tags: c

I'm making an archive program in C - I've got it traversing and writing the file contents to a single file, but I can't seem to get the `fileHeader` structure I've created (using `fwrite()`) to write into the file (only using two attributes for testing at the moment, I know more will be required). Here's my code:

```
struct fileHeader {
        char name[50];
        char path[50];  
};

void addToArch(char *inPath, char *archPath, struct fileHeader header) {
        FILE *in, *arch;
        int ch;
        arch = fopen(archPath, "ab");

        struct stat sb;
        stat(inPath, &sb);

        if(S_ISREG(sb.st_mode) == 0) {
                fprintf(arch, "\n%s\n", inPath);
                printf("Directory detected - skipped");
        }

        else {
                in = fopen(inPath, "rb");
                ch = fgetc(in);
                fwrite(&header, 1, sizeof(struct fileHeader), in);
                while (ch != EOF) {
                        fputc(ch, arch);
                        ch = fgetc(in);
                }
                fclose(in);
                fclose(arch);
                printf("File copied successfully!\n");
        }
}
```

My calling code is here:

```
//Create new file header
struct fileHeader header;
//Populate struct fields
snprintf(header.name, 50, "%s", entry->d_name);
snprintf(header.path, 50, "%s", buffer);

addToArch(buffer, "out.txt", header);
```

I've printed `entry->d_name` and `buffer` and they are definitely the strings I want going into the struct. There are no compiler errors, but no header is showing in my archive file, along with the contents.

Comment: You're mixing `in` and `arch`. Name your variables more clearly. You can do both, but for clarity and sanity, don't.

Comment: Two code review comments: (1) You can pass a pointer to const struct instead of passing the struct by value. Should be faster. (2) Writing binary data is brittle; changing from debug to relase build may already change the struct layout, let alone changing the compiler. Especially if you really want to persist data long-term ("archive program") you should take care to be language, platform and compiler independent. The canonical method would be to choose a text format of your choice like XML or JASON and write 7 bit ascii text representations.

Comment: It's writing fine now, but with ^@^@^@ between attributes - is this fine? I've memsetted the structure before filling

Comment: Thanks @PeterA.Schneider, noted

Comment: ^@ is the null character. The struct has gaps between the members which are undefined (in your case: are 0 because you zeroed the memory before). This padding is one of the reasons (besides integer sizes and float formats) why the same struct definition can differ binarily.

Answer (score 4):

Your `fwrite` is trying to write to `in`, not `arch`. Since you don't check the return value of `fwrite`, this error (trying to write to a file that's opened for read) is undetected.

Comment: Thanks for this, apologies for such a basic mistake, I thought it was something semantically I was doing wrong. I'll implement the error checks throughout

Comment: It's writing fine now, but with ^@^@^@ between attributes - is this fine? I've memsetted the structure before filling

Comment: `^@` is actually the `NUL` byte

Answer (score -2):

It seems the fwrite() call switched the number of items and size of items fields. I think it should be `fwrite(&header, sizeof(struct fileHeader), 1, arch);`